# Pin on map with label

Tags: dictionary, text, geojson

I want to create a link to map, which will show point/pin/icon with text label. 
I've found that google maps had such feature, but it is not working now.
Is there any other map, where I can display location with custom label ?
http://geojson.io looks promising, but I can't find a way to create GeoJSON with text label.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tool like [HERE XYZ Studio](https://developer.here.com/blog/managing-and-visualizing-geospatial-data-here-xyz-now-in-beta) you can create a map and customize the text labels.  For example, the image below demonstrates earthquakes with a small green text label of the magnitude of each.

[image: east coast earthquakes with text labels]

The "Mapping Seismic Activity" tutorial demonstrates how to do this step-by-step.  You can then provide a link to the map or embed it in another webapp.  If you click on "Data" or the "Pencil" you can add text or new points depending on what you want to do with it.